# cloud.google.com/go/pubsub iterator.go:44: undefined: acker and puller

Tags: go, publish-subscribe

I'm hitting the following error messages when I build codes that employ cloud.google.com/go/pubsub.
Am I working on a wrong package? Or it's just because of alpha?

```
$ go test
# cloud.google.com/go/pubsub
./iterator.go:44: undefined: acker
./iterator.go:46: undefined: puller
FAIL    cloud.google.com/go/pubsub [build failed]
```

Comment: `acker` and `puller` should be defined in `cloud.google.com/go/pubsub` if you have the full package, all its files etc. Where are you running the tests from? What folder?

Comment: The `cloud.google.com/go/pubsub` package should, besides the `iterator.go` file, contain an `acker.go` file and a `puller.go` file, the two types you're missing are defined in those two files. Do you have those two files in the pubsub folder?

Comment: When I did clean install the entire package, go get -u cloud.google.com/go, both of codes are appeared. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad you got it fixed.